# Looking for scalable spatiotemporal clustering algorithm or scalable mixed features data clustering algorithms

Tags: clustering

I want to cluster the Porto taxi dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/pkdd-15-taxi-trip-time-prediction-ii/data . After processing the dataset, I have a dataset which consists of **temporal features** (hour, day of week, holiday or not), **numerical features**, **categorical features** (like whether the taxi was ordered from a taxi stand or randomly on street etc.) and lastly **trajectories** (series latitude longitude GPS points the taxi traveled along).

Because my dataset consists of many different type of features, I can't directly cluster using an algorithm like K-Means or DBSCAN and choosing one distance metric only. So, I defined custom distance matrices for each of these categories. My plan was to use DBSCAN with custom distance metric, which would be a weighted sum of all the four different distance metrices. However, as I have around 1.5 million trips to cluster, simply taking sklearn's DBSCAN function with metric=precomputed fails due to memory issues.

I have found this paper: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/hash/fdf1bc5669e8ff5ba45d02fded729feb-Abstract.html which suggests a variant of DBSCAN, which lowers the complexity from O(n²) to O(nlog(n)). The implementation of this variant is not available, so I implemented it in python. However, in my case it takes a lot of time, even to try to cluster for numerical features only is not stopping after 1 day.

My question is: I have been working on this for so long and am very frustrated regarding what clustering approach I should take. I have looked at spatio-temporal clustering algorithms (which would only cluster based on the trajectory information, but that's a good start too!), but they all seem to be claiming that they work well for datasets up to about 200.000 dataset points (for example ST-DBSCAN).

Am I missing something? Is there no scalable clustering algorithm for spatiotemporal clustering or clustering with mixed features? I appreciate any help or hint! Thank you so much already!